# How to prompt for user Hostname while booting Ubuntu22.04 live-cd customization

Tags: 22.04, customization, live-cd

I'm customizing Ubuntu22.04 live-cd. I know how to hard code hostname while installing. But, my requirement is to prompt from hostname and take user input while installing.
Could anyone please help me or guide me to the right source?
Thanks in advance. I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference)?  You can try specifying `interactive-sections`.

For example, an autoinstall file with this snippet will prompt for the hostname.  The same section also prompts for an initial user name and password, and may result in other prompts during the install.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  interactive-sections:
    - identity
```